# Converting type of a variable from hex string to uint_32 without changing the number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, int, hex

I want to convert the string  var= "1F051440" to 1F051440 in python. I want to change the type of my variable from string to uint32 but I want to keep same content.

I know we can use Convert.ToUint32() in C#.

int(var,16) changes doesn't changes its type. It converts the number to int

Comment: Huh?  Wrap the int in `hex()` if you want to get back to a hex string.

Comment: I do not want to print it as 0x1f051440 I want to print it as 1F051440. I see in the c# Convert.ToUInt32(var, 16); Console.Writeline(string.Format("var = {0:X}",var));

Comment: `'{:X}'.format(int(var,16))`

Answer (score 0):

"1F051440" cannot be stored as an integer 1F051440. So if you want to store it as integer, you will have to convert it to integer using int("1F051440", 16) and store it that way. But when you want to print it use format function as follows:

```
var= "1F051440"
num = int(var, 16) #Store it as an integer
print(num) #Will print 520426560
print('{:X}'.format(num)) #Will print 1F051440
```

Hope this helps!